# Regex match HTML attributes names

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following element stored as a String:

```
<div class="some-class" id="my-id" data-theme="black">
   <strong data-animation="fade" disabled>Hello world!</strong>
</div>
```

I want to extract all the attributes names like this:

```
["class", "id", "data-theme", "data-animation", "disabled"]
```

This is what I tried to do, but I get also the values and dosent match the data-animation and disabled:

http://jsbin.com/hibebezibo/edit?js,console

**EDIT:**

Manged to get attributes using:

```
[\w-]+(?=\s*=\s*".*?")
```

But I still cant get the "disabled" prop.

Can someone explain me how to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use lookaheads `[\w-]+(?=\s*=\s*".*?")`

Comment: It dosent match disabled and data-animation, just animation

Comment: Recently, I have asked a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185510/regex-match-fails-on-string-with-double-quotes), so I get a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2289430) in comments that change my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using below regex which benefits from a positive lookahead you are able to match attributes' names:

```
[ ][\w-]+(?=[^<]*>)
```

*Note: Adding `-` to character class is a must.*

javascript code:

```js
const HtmlElement = `<div class="some-class" id="my-id" data-theme="black">
  <strong data-animation="fade" disabled>Hello world!</strong>
</div>`

console.log(HtmlElement.match(/ [\w-]+(?=[^<]*>)/g).map(function(element) {         
    return element.trimLeft();
}));
```

However it's not bulletproof as it can match words following a `>`. E.g:

```
<strong data-animation="fade" disabled>Hello world!></strong>
```

So it's recommended to accomplish such a task using DOM functionalities:

```js
var html = document.createElement('div');
html.innerHTML = '<div class="some-class" id="my-id" xlink:href data-theme="black"><strong data-animation="fade" disabled>Hello world!</strong></div>';
var attrNodes = document.evaluate('//*/attribute::*', html, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)

var nextAttrNode = attrNodes.iterateNext()
var arrAttrs = [];
while (nextAttrNode) {
  arrAttrs.push(nextAttrNode.name)
  nextAttrNode = attrNodes.iterateNext();
}
console.log(arrAttrs)
```

Comment: Thanks @revo, but I notice that disabled is not matched, also in case I use svg xlink:href, just xlink is matched

Comment: actually, i dont care about empty attributes, but I really need xlink:href

Answer (score 0):

This works on even nested structure.

It returns element name and its attributes

```
\<([^\/\>"]+)\s{1,}([^"]+)=\"[^"]*\"
```

Test your own regex on https://regex101.com